# Scraping HTML using lxml returns nothing even when given exact xpath

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, lxml

I have been able to scrape HTML from other sites but I have been unsuccessful with this Metacritic site. Even when given the exact xpath to an element I cannot seem to scrape any elements.

I'm trying to pull scores and the source of the score. Here's what I have for the source:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

url = "http://www.metacritic.com/movie/rogue-one-a-star-wars-story/critic-
reviews"
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#List of all critic sources for a particular movie
xpathselector="//span[@class ='source']/a"
metaElement = tree.xpath(xpathselector)
print metaElement
```

And for the one of the score elements:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

url = "http://www.metacritic.com/movie/rogue-one-a-star-wars-story/critic-
reviews"
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#List of all critic scores for a particular movie
xpathselector="//div[@class='metascore_w large movie negative indiv']"
metaElement = tree.xpath(xpathselector)
print metaElement
```

The output is always an empty list `[]`. I realize this will only print the element and I need to add `/text()` to the end of the xpath but I can't even get that far.

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: According to [Terms of Use](https://cbsi.secure.force.com/CBSi/articles/FAQ/CBS-Interactive--Terms-of-Use?retURL=%2FCBSi%2Fapex%2Fknowledgehome%3Freferer%3DmobileTerms.com&popup=false&categories=CBS_Interactive%3AmTOU&template=template_mobileTerms&referer=mobileTerms.com): "Without limiting any other provision in these Terms, you agree not to do the following, or assist others to do the following: * Engage in unauthorized spidering, “scraping,” data mining or harvesting of Content, or use any other unauthorized automated means to gather data from or about the Services"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because according to Terms of Use of the target web-site we are not allowed to assist in scraping it.

Comment: I didn't realize. Thanks @alecxe